# Return Single instead of Observable from iterable

Tags: kotlin, observable, rx-java2, iterable

I am trying to write a fun which has input as a `list of Strings` say `UserIds` and return as `Single<>`
The method looks something like this

```
fun getUserSubjectsForPeriod(userIds: List<String>, startDate: String, endDate: String): Single<Pair<String, List<UserSubjects>>> {
        return Observable.fromIterable(userIds)
             .map {id->
                 userSubjectRepository.loadUserSubjects(id, startDate, endDate)
                     .map {
                         val userSubjects = userSubjectMapper.mapToDomain(it)
                         Pair(id,userSubjects)
                     }
             }
    }
```

This function is returning

`Observable<Single<Pair<String, List<UserSubjects>>>>` instead of `Single<Pair<String, List<UserSubjects>>>`.
How do I return the required output?

Comment: You are iterating over a list of ids and creating a Pair instance with the id and the list of UserSubjects for each id. If you want to return one instance (Single) of a Pair instead many instances of the Pair (Observable), which one do you want to return? The first of the list? the last one? If you want to return all of them in a Single instead of Observable, then you are looking for a `Single<List<Pair<String, List<UserSubjects>>>>` signature instead?

Comment: I would like to return all... But I believe I do not have to do `Single<List<Pair<String, List<UserSubjects>>>>`. But my question is how do I return Single<> instead of Observable

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toList()` method of `Observable`.

I don't know the signature of `userSubjectRepository.loadUserSubjects` so I supposed that it should return `Single`

```
fun getUserSubjectsForPeriod(userIds: List<String>, startDate: String, endDate: String): Single<List<Pair<String, UserSubjects>>> {
    return Observable.fromIterable(userIds)
        .flatMapSingle { id ->
            userSubjectRepository.loadUserSubjects(id, startDate, endDate)
                .map {
                    val userSubjects = userSubjectMapper.mapToDomain(it)
                    Pair(id, userSubjects)
                }
        }.toList()
}
```

Comment: You can use `flatMapSingle` to avoid that conversion though.